# How to programmatically create instance of CakeRequest?

Tags: php, cakephp

I have Api class in Lib directory. This class have 'request' as the only method. This method accepts CakeRequest as one of the arguments. This Api method is called from UI through a component, which is working fine.

Now, I need to create a console shell, and make a call to this same Api method (Api::request). How to create instance of CakeRequest, so that it can be passed as argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can simply use:

```
$request = new CakeRequest();
```

and then you can pass the `$request` variable as argument.

This is the same as Cake does it when dispatching a request with `Dispatcher::dispatch(new CakeRequest(), new CakeResponse())`.

Comment: Thanks @Calin, that's what I have done so far. However, I am unable to populate the information inside CakeRequest object. Information like, the URL requested etc. 

Do you know any way of doing this?

Comment: Are you initializing it from a console shell? `CakeRequest` automatically populates the url (if not already supplied) from the `$_SERVER` array, and parses the environment ($_POST, $_GET, $_FILES). But in a console shell you don't have any of these.

Comment: Yes, I need to initialize it from console shell only.

Comment: Well, in a shell you don't have a browser environment, so no URL, $_POST etc.. If what you want is to simulate a `CakeRequest` object as  if it originated from a browser, you'll need to populate the information manually.

Comment: Got it..! Empty object created with new CakeRequest() works. And for rest of the things, you can create shell task and make use of App::uses() for controllers and models you need. Closing this question.

Comment: Calin, maybe you would know how to make a post request in this case ? tks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24884622/create-instance-of-cakerequest-with-type-post-cakephp