# Create instance of CakeRequest with type post - cakephp

Tags: cakephp, post, request

Here is the same question,
[How to programmatically create instance of CakeRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15220047/how-to-programmatically-create-instance-of-cakerequest)

just in my case I want to create `post` request

```
$request = new CakeRequest('/posts/view');
$request->data = array('key' => 'value');
```

I tried to use this

```
$request->addDetector('post', 
    array (
        'env' => 'REQUEST_METHOD',
        'value' => 'POST' 
    )
);
```

but when I echo `$this->request->method()` on next page, it always outputs `GET`. How can I set request type as `post` ?

**update**
cake version 2.3

**update2**

what actually Im trying to do, is this: lets say I have a form for creating a post, with title and content fields. Now, if the user is not logged in, under that form I am showing signin/signup form's inputs(so I have just one form on that page), so the user will fill in the username/password for sign in or signup info and click `signin and publish` or `signup and publish` button, if he chose to signup. After saving the post's info in the db's table's temporary row and/or in session I need to authenticate the user, for that I want to send post request for users' controller's  `signup and publish` action, and to not change the those signup/signin functions(were im checking the post request) I wanted to create this post request. I know I can also move signin/signup action to some component, so I can use them from different controllers, but signup action has a lot of other parts, and it uses other functions and components, and I would not prefer to move all that logic into component.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you need to do that in the first place? Outside of test cases this feels kinda wrong. If you'd explain your intentions, then someone might be able to find a better way of solving whatever you are trying to solve. ps, please always mention your exact CakePHP version!

Answer (score 0):

You can fake a post request by modifying the PHP superglobals, which `CakeRequest` parses:

```php
$_POST = array('key' => 'value');
$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] = 'POST';
$request = new CakeRequest('/posts/view');
```

However **this is a hack and should be avoided**. I can't imagine a scenario where you would want to use something like this.

Comment: yeah, this came to my mind, but it is a dirty hack, as u also said, so I thought maybe it could be a cake way of doing that. Just needed in my code, though there are workarounds, but this would be better. Thanks for ur response.